# Are there any recent experiments demonstrating retrocausality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, causality

I was wondering if there are any recent experiments outside of the typical quantum mechanics single particle realm that demonstrate that [retrocausality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocausality) is more than pseudo-science?

Comment: What turns up when you Google it, I am guessing not very much? Are there any proposed, mainstream experiments in your search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not what you have in mind, because it's hard to interpret quantum experiments without making additional assumptions.  The entanglement experiments that violate Bell-inequalities can be interpreted as evidence for *either* retrocausality or nonlocality.  If you assume a local reality in space and time, then they are experimental evidence for retrocausality.  If you assume no-retrocausality (as is almost always done), those same experiments are evidence for nonlocality.

There's also a relevant recent paper by two very-highly-regarded people in quantum foundations:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.07871 .  They show that even single particle experiments, combined with a certain reasonable assumption about time-symmetry, imply retrocausality.